# Removing lines on coast side using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, line, delete

I have a shapefile of European countries (with regional subdivisions) as well as a shapefile of lines.

How do I delete all the lines on the coast-side, using ArcGIS Desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a shapefile of lines, I'm assuming it would include the coastline? If this is the case, you could simply: increase the transparency to 100% that would make the coastlines "disappear".  This is found under Layer Properties >
Display tab

[image]

or you could change the symbology to no color which is also found under Layer Properties> Symbology tab

[image]

The methodology is assuming you're using ArcMap.  If you could elaborate on the software you're using, that would help to determine a solution.